# Facing assertion failure error while login ios app with xmpp frame work : ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I am trying to implement chat application. Trying to login with authorized user name and password. Already registered in ejabbered account. But, while, login, I am facing this following error. Kindly guide me, how to solve this.

**Error**

```
*** Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain], /Users/Downloads/my_ChatInteg/myChatInteg/Classes/HelperClasses/KeychainItemWrapper.m:309
2015-10-10 18:50:28.997 myChatInteg[1057:34611] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
```

**keyChainWrapper.m**

```
- (void)writeToKeychain
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = NULL;
    NSMutableDictionary *updateItem = NULL;
    OSStatus result;

    if (SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)genericPasswordQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&attributes) == noErr)
    {
        // First we need the attributes from the Keychain.
        updateItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attributes];
        // Second we need to add the appropriate search key/values.
        [updateItem setObject:[genericPasswordQuery objectForKey:(id)kSecClass] forKey:(id)kSecClass];

        // Lastly, we need to set up the updated attribute list being careful to remove the class.
        NSMutableDictionary *tempCheck = [self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData];
        [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecClass];

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        // Remove the access group if running on the iPhone simulator.
        //
        // Apps that are built for the simulator aren't signed, so there's no keychain access group
        // for the simulator to check. This means that all apps can see all keychain items when run
        // on the simulator.
        //
        // If a SecItem contains an access group attribute, SecItemAdd and SecItemUpdate on the
        // simulator will return -25243 (errSecNoAccessForItem).
        //
        // The access group attribute will be included in items returned by SecItemCopyMatching,
        // which is why we need to remove it before updating the item.
        [tempCheck removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
#endif

        // An implicit assumption is that you can only update a single item at a time.

        result = SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef)updateItem, (CFDictionaryRef)tempCheck);
        NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't update the Keychain Item." );
    }
    else
    {
        // No previous item found; add the new one.
        result = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)[self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData], NULL);
        NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't add the Keychain Item." );  //APP CRASHES IN THIS LINE
    }
}
```

**Saving values in key chain**

```
-(BOOL)saveCredentials:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
    if([TCUtility saveToKeyChain:[dictionary valueForKey:@"username"] andPassword:[dictionary valueForKey:@"password"]])
    {
        if([XAppDelegate getCredentialsFromKeychain]){
            return YES;
        }else{
            return NO;
        }

    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show your code when you set your user/pass in your keychain ?

Comment: how you set your  data into keychain ? ( show your code  )

Comment: I updated my code. @MohamadFarhand

Comment: i recommend to check you value to be nil !

Answer (score 0):

i recommend  you do like this :

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keyChainManager = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]initWithIdentifier:APP_KEYCHAIN accessGroup:nil];
[keyChainManager setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlways forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];
[keyChainManager setObject:yourObject forKey:key];
```

**please prevent to add duplicate item**

Comment: a const name  for keychain for example youbapp name-keychain

Comment: _keyChain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]  accessGroup:nil];

Comment: we have used, appBundle. how to add keychain??

Comment: please see my answer , i have wrote for you 

Comment: I couldn find key chain name? How can I find that??

Comment: am using bundle identifier as Key chain name. Is it right? If it is wrong means, how can I find keychain name?

Comment: @McDonal_11 you can use any name @"helooo" @"yourappname_keychain" or any string my bro :)